# how to take certain information in my csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

this is my first row of csv. I have 11000 of them in a column

```
"
► Contact with patient | 04.09.2019 |  |
► receive the job | 04.09.2019 |  |
► contact with patient  | 04.09.2019 |  |
► take all docs and read  | 05.09.2019 |  |
► is there any docs to send | 19.09.2019 |  |
► take the contract | 20.09.2019 |  |
► Actualise the contract | 20.09.2019 |  |
► take the contact | 20.09.2019 |  | "
```

I am trying to take the last written part of this csv (► take the contact | 20.09.2019 |  |), they are all different some have 10 parts some 2 but I always need the last date to put it into a new column. What method should I use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
row = """
Contact with patient | 04.09.2019 |  |
receive the job | 04.09.2019 |  |
contact with patient  | 04.09.2019 |  |
take all docs and read  | 05.09.2019 |  |
is there any docs to send | 19.09.2019 |  |
take the contract | 20.09.2019 |  |
Actualise the contract | 20.09.2019 |  |
take the contact | 20.09.2019 |  | """

r = row.split('|')  # split in a list

r = r[-4:]  # keep the 4 last elements

r = '|'.join(r)  # join them together
```

or the same in one line:

```
r = '|'.join(row.split('|')[-4:])
```

print(r) # take the contact | 20.09.2019 |  |

Comment: and if I want to do that for the entire csv I just read it with pandas and then do the loop for each row and write it in a new column

Comment: This way works if you open the csv file as text file, read data line by line, process data and store in list. I don't know how you can manage it with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/crosscheck/crosscheck/sheet1')
r = df.split('|')
r = r[-4:]
r = '|'.join(r)
print(r)
```

still getting the error 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'